# OrientDB - unable to read from socket

Tags: php, server, orientdb, graph-databases

I want to use OrientDB to store some data on a server, localhost for now. Using the official library from https://github.com/orientechnologies/PhpOrient. 
However, when trying to connect I get the following failure message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PhpOrient\Exceptions\SocketException' with message 
'socket_read(): unable to read from socket [104]: Connection reset by peer' in 
/Library/WebServer/Documents/T1/vendor/ostico/phporient/src/PhpOrient/Protocols/Binary/OrientSocket.php on line 147
```

What can be wrong? I can connect and go into to the OrientDB Studio on localhost:2480, but here something seems to be going wrong.

```
<?php 
require "../vendor/autoload.php";
use PhpOrient\PhpOrient;

$client = new PhpOrient( 'localhost', 2480 );
$client->connect('root','pwd'); 
echo "1";
$client->dbList();
?>
```

Comment: If the answer worked for you, you should mark it as your accepted answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 4):

Try the connection with this code:

```
<?php
require "../vendor/autoload.php";
use PhpOrient\PhpOrient;
$client = new PhpOrient();
$client->hostname = 'localhost';
$client->port     = 2424;
$client->username = 'root';
$client->password = 'pwd';
$client->connect();
echo "DB list: <br /><br /> ";
echo '<pre>'; print_r($client->dbList()); echo '</pre>';
echo "<br /> <br /> DB Listed above successfully!";
?>
```

You should use 2424 port.
Hope it helps.